# On Developing Native Windows Executables

Tags: windows, user-interface, executable, native

Which technology stack do you recommend for developing native windows executable (has GUI), other than .NET stack?

Other that C++ (MFC, ...) some could be named; yet which one is mature and pragmatic enough?

1. Delphi 7?
2. Common Lisp (Which one is proper for developing GUI?)?
3. Scheme?
4. Qt or wxXXX stack?

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in your question.  You're asking about mature technologies for developing native windows executables, yet you immediately (apparently) rule out C++/MFC with no explanation.  You appear to be leading us to an answer without explaining an apparent bias against specific answers. Please explain further.

Comment: What are your criteria?  Why rule out the .NET stack, which is often the easiest path?

Comment: Thanks

@SAMills I did not intend to rule out C++/MFC. I should say "beside C++/MFC...". It is just I will prefer something else with same level of maturity (if exists such a thing) to C++/MFC.

@Cheeso I am deploying a lot of data (which I want to be well protected) and a lot of algorithms (which I want to prevent them from being decompiled) and I need high performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For native Win32 GUI apps, I've found nothing that beats [Delphi](http://embarcadero.com/products/delphi).  (Your question asks about Delphi 7, but please note that all versions of Delphi (including the latest - Delphi 2010) can produce single, standalone .EXEs).

Comment: Just want to mention C++ Builder, which may be more appealing if OP is already familiar with C++.

Answer (score 1):

[Python](http://www.python.org/) is a good choice for some sorts of problems, and you can package python programs into a single .exe using py2exe.
Here is a nice py2exe tutorial: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Tcl/Tk is very mature, has a small footprint, is easy to learn and use, and uses native widgets on Windows and the Mac. Plus, it has a deployment mechanism second to none by way of starpacks, starkits and tclkits. You can either create a single-file executable ([starpack](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3663)) that embeds a very full featured virtual filesystem, or a two-file solution of a platform-specific runtime engine ([tclkit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/52)) with a platform-independent application file ([starkit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3661)).

It's downside is that it's low on "flash" -- there's not a lot of support for transparency, multimedia, animation and fancy graphics. So, depending on whether or not you need a lot of eye candy it may or may not be the right choice for you.